# Clarification on the domain of $\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2})$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse

As the title says, I don't understand how to find the domain of $\arcsin(\sqrt{1-x^2})$. I *kinda* understand how it would equate to it would be -1 < x < 1 (inclusive of 1 and -1) by definition of a real root, but how does the inverse sine function affect this domain? I know that for any function $\arcsin(f(x))$, the domain is $-1<f(x)<1$, but how exactly does the root affect this domain also?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BEcause arcsin operates on values between $-1$ and $1$, you need to have
$$
-1 \le \sqrt{1 - x^2} \le 1
$$
That's equivalent (by squaring, since the square root is always nonnegative) to
$$
{1 - x^2} \le 1
$$
But with the constraint that $1 - x^2 \ge 0$, so that the square root is still defined. So we have
$$
0 \le {1 - x^2} \le 1
$$

Take $1 - \text{each term}$ and swap the comparisons to get
$$1 \ge x^2 \ge 0
$$
whose solution is $-1 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but in your second last line why is it that only x^2<1 is counted?

Is it because x^2>0 is true for all values of real x anyways?

Comment: The third to last line has the form $a \le b \le c$; I changed it to $1-a \ge 1-b \ge 1-c$. Perhaps it's the previous statement, "the constraint that $1 - x^2 \ge 0,...$" that's confusing; the point is that if $x^2$ is larger than 1, then $1 - x^2$ is negative, and square root won't be defined.

Comment: Sorry, I'm mainly referring to your last line. Why isn't it stated that x≥0 also, alongside −1≤x≤1?

Comment: The previous line, which I'll rewrite as $0 \le x^2 \le 1$, describes a set of numbers: *all* those whose squares are between $0$ and $1$. The numbers between 0 and 1 are such numbers, but there are others as well: consider $x = -1/2$; its square is $1/4$, which is between $0$ and $1$. So it, too, must be included in the set of solutions: when you go from a line like $0 \le x^2 \le 1$ to a line like $a \le x \le b$, you're supposed to choose $a$ and $b$ so that the two inequalities describe identical sets. (Just as with equations each equation should have the same roots at the prior one).

Answer (score 0):

The domain of the function $f(x)=\arcsin(x)$, by definition, is equal to $-1\le x\le 1$. Now, since the argument in your function is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ then we have to solve the following inequality:
$$-1\le \sqrt{1-x^2} \le 1.$$

Since the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ is greater than $0$ for all $x$, then we note that 
$$0 \le \sqrt{1-x^2} \le 1 $$
$$\therefore 0\le1-x^2\le1$$
$$\therefore-1\le-x^2\le0$$
$$\therefore 0\le x^2 \le1$$
$$\therefore x\in[-1,1]$$.

Comment: When are you able to square all parts of the inequality?

Comment: The algebra is perfectly sound.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by that :P

Comment: Squaring all sides of the inequality is perfectly fine.

Comment: But are you always able to square all sides of an inequality?

Comment: For simple ones like this, yes. See [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/SolveLinearInequalities.aspx) and the following pages for revision on inequalities.

Comment: Actually, for $x\le y \lt 0,  x^2\ge y^2$. The type shown in the answer generally only holds for x,y both postive (and perhaps in some specific cases where one of them is negative and one of them is positive. However, in most contexts where you encounter this type of things, you wouldn't be able to know beforehand)